# ios - load data one by one inside uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a array with 1000 items and I want to show one by one item into uiscrollview, means that every time it will load the first item displayed in UIScrollView instead load all 1000 items.

I have try but doesn't work, it still load all 1000 items. So how to do that?

snip code:

```
for (int e=0; e<1000; e++) {
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
    [scrollView addSubview:viewText];
    [scrollView addSubview:viewTime];
    [scrollView addSubview:lblText1];
    [scrollView addSubview:lblText2];
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Can you explain exactly what effect you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: not have any effect here at all, I want to display each item in uiscroll 1000 items on display instead of all at once. Do you understand?

Comment: No.  I don't understand.  You didn't rephrase anything.  I don't understand what you mean by "all at once".

Comment: "all at once" meant that when i have 1000 items in array, service will download 1000 items then show in uiscrollview.

Comment: I don't want to do so, i want to download 1000 items then display one by one item in uiscrollview

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this incorrectly. You should be using the [UITableView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=YtqrUqKPC4ftkQehw4CIBg&usg=AFQjCNExfg0PVyXsvmr4DeBhLPhUWqkT_w&sig2=YKT4ZxBCCumRgNispX56lw&bvm=bv.57967247,d.eW0) class as it uses a set of reusable cells to display information so that you don't have to load non-visible information into memory. I suggest you start here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer,the example is very good, but i need to show data in uiscrollview.

Comment: @BlueSky Might I ask why?

Comment: @BlueSky - UITableView has its own scrollView so its behavior like scrollView and also you can hide separator line of tableview. so from my own experience **0x7fffffff** is absoluty right :)

Comment: yeah, uitableview very good but in this time i need uiscrollview, I need to show data form EPG, do you know EPG. Can you see it: http://www.padmania.de/app-on-air-das-tv-programm-im-deutschsprachigen-raum/